# localhost not working when using wi-fi hotspot on Iphone 4

Tags: linux-mint, iphone

I've just moved out of an office where `localhost` would load a web application I am working on (apache2).  I used the buildings wi-fi when at the office.

Now I am using a wi-fi hotspot on iPhone 4 in another building and typing `localhost` in both Chrome and Firefox loads a page of google search results, rather than the web application.

Is this a "known issue" that `localhost` operates differently when connected to an iPhone hotspot via wi-fi?

And if so, how do I get `localhost` to work as per usual?

**System Info**

Operating System: Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon 64-bit

Cinnamon Version: 2.6.13

Linux Kernel: 3.16.0-29-generic

iPhone: 4

iOS: 7.1.2 (11D257)

**Update/Solution**

Sorry, I think the addition of detail distorted my presentation of what the issue actually was.

I rephrased the issue as:

"Why can't I access localhost without an internet connection".

And found this solution, which worked:

https://askubuntu.com/a/2983

```
Check that you have this line in /etc/hosts:

127.0.0.1       localhost

If it is not there, add it.
```

Thanks for your efforts in providing a solution though, I'm sure I and others will be able use the information in the future.

Comment: If you have solved your question than answer rather than editing the current question...

Answer (score 0):

Command :

```
ifconfig
```

If you are using wireless connection than you will look at wlan0 there's an ip address given.

[image]

If you are using ethernet than, look at eth0. You will get ip there also. If you are using ethernet.. Check that if you can use localhost by that ip. Like I am doing [image]. My ip is 192.168.0.107 so, try to add it as Url. If you unable to open by that url it means you ip address is bound somehow. **You don't have to use Hotspot**. Just connect to local wifi. Then, try to open that url in your mobile... As earlier I said if you are unable to open that url it means your ip address is bound. Don't try `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` in android.

Answer (score -1):

localhost will work on your local web server. if you want to connect to your webserver (on Linux machine) using "localhost" domain, you have to configure your static DNS records.

since you may not be able to config your DNS records file on iphone, you can set an external DNS on your Wifi (the hotspot that you're connected to) that refers to your Linux system that is running the web server.

to do this, follow the instruction on your iphone:

settings => Wi-Fi => HotspotName => info =>Static =>DNS

then, set the IP address of Linux machine as your DNS.

then in the "/etc/hosts" of your Linux system, you should add:

```
localhost    LinuxIPAddr
```

where "LinuxIPAddr" is the IP address of your Linux machine.

so, when you type "localhost" on your phone, your iphone requests the Linux machine the IP address of "localhost" domain, and the Linux machine responds the IP address, so your problem will be solved. :)

Comment: No.  localhost is 127.0.0.1  - changing it in /etc/hosts to some other IP address will break all kinds of things